# How to enable logging for Default ConnectionPool in customized RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, connection-pooling, resttemplate

In one of my project(`spring-mvc` Not `spring-boot`) we have customized Bean configuration of `RestTemplate`(below).
This is used at multiple places to make several in multi-threaded environment. Call to all routes works fine except one. For that one we are getting blocked / throttled on our end due to `ResourceAccessException`.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://abc.xyz.com/Search": Request aborted; nested exception is org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestAbortedException: Request aborted
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:674)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:636)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:557)
        at
```

Since it is happening just for one route and not for all routes we think problem is because lot of requests comes for that route and default pool used in ResTemplate might be reason. As a first step we want to be sure of this so wanted to enable appropriate log for  [ClientConnectionPoolManager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html)  so that as a next step we can tweak the values of pool so that we no longer see any throttling to calls to that route.

I don't see any logging in the `ClientConnectionPoolManager` and `RestTemplate` source files so how to enable logging for them to get pooling values?

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("ssl-bypass-all")
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

    SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
            .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added just one line in log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager=DEBUG, HttpConnectionPool
```

Whole log4j.properties file is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Default
log4j.appender.Default=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Default.File=${APP_HOME}/logs/app-name.log
log4j.appender.Default.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Default.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{DATE}] %-5p %c %x - [%X{profiler-ink}] : %m%n%n
log4j.appender.Default.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.Default.MaxBackupIndex=200
log4j.appender.Default.Append=true


log4j.logger.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager=DEBUG, HttpConnectionPool

log4j.appender.HttpConnectionPool=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.HttpConnectionPool.File=${APP_HOME}/logs/check-availability-pool.log
log4j.appender.HttpConnectionPool.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HttpConnectionPool.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{DATE}] %-5p %c %x - [%X{profiler-ink}] : %m%n%n
log4j.appender.HttpConnectionPool.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.HttpConnectionPool.MaxBackupIndex=200
log4j.appender.HttpConnectionPool.Append=true
```